# Error sending JSON object to asp.net WebMethod, using jQuery

Tags: .net, jquery, ajax

I get an error of "Cannot convert object of type System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[...+ContactHolder]'"

This is my C# code:

```
public class ContactHolder{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string AddContact(Object items){
    List<ContactHolder> contacts = new JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType<List<ContactHolder>>(items);
    return String.Format("You added {0} contacts!", contacts.ToString());
}
```

This is my Javascript code (note I have included jquery-1.4.1.js and json2.js in my project)

```
function Test() {
var arr = new Array();
var contact = new Object();
contact.Name = "Ben";
contact.Address = "Ohio";

var contact2 = new Object();
contact.Name = "Jon";
contact.Address = "Illinois";

arr[1] = contact;
arr[2] = contact2;

var DTO = JSON.stringify(arr);
PageMethods.AddContact(DTO, OnMyMethodComplete);}

function OnMyMethodComplete(result, userContext, methodName) {alert(result);}
```

When I pass DTO into myPageMethod it looks like this: "[{"Name":"Ben","Address":"Ohio"},{"Name":"Jon","Address":"Illinois"}]"

When it appears in my WebMethod as items it looks like this: "[{\"Name\":\"Ben\",\"Address\":\"Ohio\"},{\"Name\":\"Jon\",\"Address\":\"Illinois\"}]"

The code errors on the call to JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType, the message is {"Cannot convert object of type System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[...+ContactHolder]'"}

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `PageMethods.AddContact`? I think it would be more easier to help you if we know exactly what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Why do you not declare the WebMethod parameter as ContactHolder[] ? Seems as if ASP.Net sees a scalar parameter (Object), and converts the JSON string into a .Net string.

Comment: @Herberth - I do include the code for AddContact. It is in the C# code section.

Comment: @Devio - I tried that, I get the same error. It just changes to can't convert into List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Passing parameter to WebMethod with jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736058/problem-passing-parameter-to-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax)

Remove `JSON.stringify` or do like this:

[sending JSON object successfully to asp.net WebMethod, using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146110/problem-sending-json-object-succesfully-to-asp-net-webmethod-using-jquery/1162544#1162544)

Comment: This is correct.  When using the ASP.NET AJAX service proxy helper methods, the parameters are automatically JSON serialized before sending.  You *do* need the JSON.stringify() call if you're calling the service directly, without the service proxy.  For example, if you're using jQuery's $.ajax().

Comment: Thanks Dave, I just found your answer in similar topic and linked it.