# Send JSON with Ajax to ASP.NET Web Method

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, webmethod

This is first time I am attempting to send data to server using Ajax. I followed lot of answers from here but I won't just stop getting the error : `"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027Products\u0027."`

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1149036/2417645) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162544/2417645) but still the same. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
        var products =  [ { ProductId : 1, ProductName : "Mercedes", Category : "Cars", Price : 25000 }, { ProductId : 2, ProductName : "Otobi", Category : "Furniture", Price : 20000 } ];

    function GetProductId() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GenerateQrCode",
            data: { "Products" : products.toString()  },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Success');
            }
        });
    }


[WebMethod]
    public static void GenerateQrCode(object Products)
    {
        //Cannot get to here
    }
```

Comment: try : `data: { Products : products },` jQuery will parse the object for you-

Comment: This is not working. Same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
data : "{'Products':" + JSON.stringify(products) + "}"
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is working but it is only working on Chrome but not in IE10. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
data : {Products: JSON.stringify(products)}
```

or

```
data : {Products: products}
```