# Passing complex JSON to a WebMethod

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax, webmethod

I'm trying to pass an JSON that has the following structure:

> {"var":"{"var1:"val1","var2:"val2",...,"varN:"valN"}"}

My JS function executing the following POST function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyWebApp.aspx/Foo",
    data:  {"json":"{"var1:"val1","var2:"val2",...,"varN:"valN"}"},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("2D JSON Test is done")
    }
});
```

I want to know how to define the WebMethod function prototype to receive the JSONs like this?

> ```
> [WebMethod]
> public static void Foo(var json)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> [WebMethod]
> public static void Foo(string json)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> [WebMethod]
> public static void Foo(string[] json)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> [WebMethod]
> public static void Foo(List<string> json)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the link:[sending JSON object successfully to asp.net WebMethod, using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146110/problem-sending-json-object-succesfully-to-asp-net-webmethod-using-jquery)

```
[WebMethod]
        public static void Foo(object items)
        {
            //break point here
            List<object> lstItems = new JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType<List<object>>(items);
        }
```